# segmen fault for RSA_size() and EVP_PKEY_size() after use EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA() or EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA()

Tags: c++, openssl

why RSA_size() and EVP_PKEY_size() will crash after i call EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA() or EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA() in my code?

openssl version is 1.10.

If i do not call EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA() or EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(),program run correctly .

Also, I think those two function are both using to set RSA_st from EVP_PKEY,Am i got some misunderstanding of those two functions?

```
void testfun(char **argc) {

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    EVP_PKEY *prikey = nullptr, *pubkey = nullptr;
    BIO *prifile = nullptr, *pubfile = nullptr;
    RSA *pubrsa = nullptr, *prirsa = nullptr, *newra = nullptr;

    prifile = BIO_new_file(argc[1], "r");

    char passwd[] = "1111";
    prikey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    prikey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(prifile, nullptr, 0, passwd);

    prirsa = RSA_new();

    /* all those code block combination will cause segmentation fault
     * 1-3
     * 1-4
     * 2-3
     * 2-4
     * and output will be correct if i only use code block 3
     * */

    //1
    //cout << EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(prikey, prirsa) << endl;

    //2
    //cout << EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(prikey, prirsa) << endl;

    //3
    //cout << EVP_PKEY_size(prikey) << endl;

    //4
    //cout << RSA_size(prirsa) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `RSA_new()` and not `RSA_generate_key()` (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RSA_generate_key.html)?

Comment: Sorry i don't really get your point. Actually the code i want to achive is read key(not only RSA private key) from PEM file to EVP_PKEY. In this example, i want to set RSA-st from EVP_PKEY. So i don't think i should use RSA_generate_key(). ths for u reply

Comment: `RSA_key` allocates RSA object but it's not a ready to use key. If you read a key from PEM that's okay because this would assign a properly initialized structure. What's the behaviour of your program when you read the key instead of using this `RSA_key`?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, it just an example for me to learn openssl API. There are no extra action in my program. And i know i can use EVP_PKEY to do encrypt/decrypt and so on, i just want to know why the program will crash? Am i misunderstanding the function so the usage is wrong ? Or maybe there are wrong config of environment in my computer(can you run this function?). Or other problems.

Comment: I can check it out later, but it seems you're providing incorrectly initialized structure - without RSA key (but allocated to have one). You'll get RSA key by either generating it or reading it from i.e. file. Then those functions should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for you enthusiastic. I just find an Description error in my comment. The code will run correctly for code block 3 (not 4), Is that misleading you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSA_size` crash

`RSA_size` takes an RSA pointer and returns the key's modulus size - the provided key must be initialized, according to https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/RSA_size.html *`rsa->n` must **not** be NULL*. Your `RSA_new` does not create the key - it only allocates the structure. So you can't call a function that extracts size from a non-existent key.

`EVP_PKEY_size` crash

`EVP_PKEY_size` reason for crash is basically the same - you assign incorrect key to the existing, correct key (given that you provided a correct one in `BIO_new_file`.

So, the code that you probably seek is:

1. Generate the RSA key with password 1111, like so:

   openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
2. Run the program with the following code:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <openssl/evp.h>
   #include <openssl/pem.h>
   #include <cassert>

   int main() {
       OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

       // UNUSED
       // *pubkey = nullptr;
       // *pubfile = nullptr;
       // RSA *pubrsa = nullptr, *prirsa = nullptr, *newra = nullptr;

       BIO * prifile = BIO_new_file("../private.pem", "r");
       assert(prifile);

       char passwd[] = "1111";
       //prikey = EVP_PKEY_new(); // why allocate if you assign it somewhere else? memory leak!
       EVP_PKEY * prikey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(prifile, nullptr, 0, passwd);
       assert(prikey);

       //1
       //std::cout << EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(prikey, prirsa) << std::endl;

       //2
       //std::cout << EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(prikey, prirsa) << std::endl;

       //3 Should correctly output 256 (modulo size in bytes)
       std::cout << EVP_PKEY_size(prikey) << std::endl;

       //4
       //std::cout << RSA_size(prirsa) << std::endl;

       std::cout << "done\n";
       return 0;
   }
   ```

You don't need `EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA` nor `EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA` to read your key. The function `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` does all of that for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!     now i know where i was wrong.EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA() and EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA() make " EVP_PKEY = RSA " not "RSA = EVP_PKEY", So prirsa wasn't set then prikey reference to NULL.  Could i ask HOW can i make "RSA = EVP_PKEY"?

Comment: Do you mean extracting RSA private key from the EVP_PKEY structure? `RSA* prirsa = EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA(prikey); assert(prirsa);`

Comment: Yes, That is what i mean. My problem is completely solved (so ashamed,all come from English comprehension). Thanks again